# DynamicRouteValueTransformer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes, .net-7.0

I have this route is register on Program.cs

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "admin",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapDynamicControllerRoute<SlugRouteValueTransformer>("/{**slug}");
```

Each request to the URI it will call SlugRouteValueTransformer method then it will call the controller/action or api/controller/action

I would like each of the request it will try to call into the route
controller/action or api/controller/action first, if the route is not available then go to SlugRotueValueTransformer

Comment: Do you mean when you make a request, for example `/Home/Index`, you get into the method in `SlugRotueValueTransformer`? This is for sure, because `MapControllerRoute`, `MapDynamicControllerRoute`, etc. are all middleware, and they will be executed by default. The page you displayed should still be `/Home/Index`, because it still matches your exact route.

Comment: [This document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#attribute-route-order) states that Routing builds a tree and matches all endpoints simultaneously.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding the matching of routes. When you initiate a request, it will start matching from the first route to the last route. If no order is specified, the definition order of the route is its priority.

Comment: This means that when you have matched the corresponding route, the following routes will still be matched until the last one.

Comment: As I mentioned When I request /Home/Index it will go to SlugRouteValueTransformer first then it will go to /Home/Index Controller.

I want to go to /Home/Index and skip SlugRouteValueTransformer.

Comment: Maybe you can't skip its execution, this is ASP.NET Core Router's design.